# cannot access org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, compiler-errors

I've added org.eclipse.core.runtime-3.7.0.jar library to classpath. I'm using Maven to manage project's dependencies. I also tried adding related dependency to pom.xml of module but the word `<dependency></dependency>` turned into red. So I removed that. Basically, the problem was supposed to be solved when I added org.eclipse.core.runtime-3.7.0.jar file to classpath but it didn't. When I compile I get this error:
Error:(13, 8) java: cannot access org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor
  class file for org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor not found

Answer (score 6):

`IProgressMonitor` is in the `org.eclipse.equinox.common` plugin.

Note: `org.eclipse.equinox.common` and `org.eclipse.core.runtime` are Eclipse plugins and will generally **not** work in a plain Java program. They must be used by an Eclipse plugin or RCP.